# Erro ao instanciar Context com Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

To pegando o Entity Framework para aprender, mas quando vou executar meu código, retorna o seguinte erro:

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Regras de segurança de herança foram
>   violadas pelo tipo: 'MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration'. Os tipos
>   derivados devem corresponder à acessibilidade de segurança do tipo de
>   base ou ser menos acessíveis

Linha do erro:

```
EntityContext contexto = new EntityContext();
```

Classe EntityContext:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public class EntityContext : DbContext
{
    public EntityContext() : base("MyContext")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>();
    }
}
```

App.Config:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MyContext" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
     connectionString="server=localhost;database=teste;uid=root;password="/>
</connectionStrings>
```

O que pode estar acontecendo? Como consertar?

Comment: Tem como você procurar pela _string_  `MySqlEFConfiguration` dentro do web.config?

Comment: Parece ser algum erro de violação de herança a classe base, vc já chegou a verificar como está as heranças das classes que vc está utilizando? Já tentou usar sem essa propriedade abaixo?
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]